# launching automator with keywords

Tags: macos, automator

Using `automator`, I would like to launch some webpages as soon as I type some keywords in any application. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is able to be done with Automator in a number of ways. One of many ways to do this is to create a service in Automator and then set the keyboard shortcut using System Preferences. In Automator, one would simply create a service and set: Service receives `no input` in `any application`, then add `Get Specified URLs`(and specify the webpages you want to open), followed by `Display Webpages`. After saving the service, one would set the keyboard shortcut by opening System Preferences >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts >>Services. At the bottom of the page(under 'General'), the service would appear. They would then check the box next to it if it isn't already, and they would click on `add shortcut`(and type the shortcut).

[image: The Automator Service]